# List of SX sites

Tags: discussion, big-list, se-sites

I have asked several questions on several SX sites. For now I know the following:

1. [Math SX](https://math.stackexchange.com/);
2. [Tex SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/);
3. [mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net);
4. [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com);
5. [Japanese SX](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/);
6. [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/);
7. [AskDifferent (aka Apple SX)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/);
8. [English SX](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

I was wondering if there were any more and if we could try building a list of them for the use of users who have a question and are not sure where to ask. For example, I could have used such a list when asking a question which was for apple SX, but which I asked on stackoverflow because I knew the latter and not the former. I wasn't sure on which meta to ask this because it is a cross-question related to all SX sites, and I didn't exactly know what to tag it with. So could anyone help me completing (or more likely expanding) this list?

Comment: Alternatively, scroll all the way to the bottom of the page on a nonmobile browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on the StackExchange-logo on the top left part of this page and then click on "more stack exchange communities". You will get to [this](http://stackexchange.com/sites#users) site, that lists all sites.